# Make a queryset in which the children meet a condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an API with Django Rest Framework and in one of my endpoints I need to return the father and the children that meet the condition active = True

These are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)



class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And this is my queryset:

```
queryset = Category.objects.filter(products__active=True)
```

I have the serializer configured to return the categories along with their products.

I would like the response to be all the categories with the only active products but it returns all the categories with the active and inactive products

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your query has nothing to do with the `rest framework` and is purely Django. From the model that you have posted, neither `Category` nor `Product` has a field name `active`. If they have, please update your question. But assuming that they don't have, this should be your model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # or False


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # or False
```

This way, the ones that are active will be in your query.

Update:
You can get active products this way:

```
 products = Product.objects.filter(active=true)
```

You can get `Categories` with an active product this way:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(product__active=True)
```

Update 2:
I am not quite sure what you are planning to do with the data but from comments, if you want to loop through active products of every category, this is the way:

```
for c in categories:
    active_products = Product.objects.filter(active=True, category=c)
    for p in active_products:
        print(p.title) # or anything else you want
```

Comment: I didn't test the queries, if they don't work let me know, I test them and give you the correct ones.

Comment: Sorry Ramtin, I have already edited the question. I come from php Symfony and I'm new to Python Django. I would just like to make a query that returns me the categories only with active products

Comment: Hi again Ramtin, that doesn't work for me. I get error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'products_set' into field."

Comment: @AntonioTapias Sorry about that, it is `product` not `product_set`, I corrected the answer

Comment: It is not what I need. I need the query to return all the categories and their products but only the products that are active

Comment: I want if I do a loop in category.products, only there are only active products

Comment: I added an update. Just remember that you cannot have two types of object in the same query object. You can, however, get one object and access the related objects through that. for example, get the `product` and access its category by `product.category`